# Plot slope-area graph

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am doing hydrological analysis for a river network in a DTM.
I have produced a graph like (b).
Now, I want to take it one step further and plot a log slope-area graph like graph (a).

[image]

How do I calculate slope and area for the catchment?
I assume the (+) on the graph show slope of diferent rivers?  If so, how do I calculate the slope from the DTM?

I am working with ArcGIS Pro latest version and MATLAB.

Comment: See if this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181906/calculating-average-stream-slope-at-each-location-along-stream-using-arcgis-desk/181956#181956 helps